# I want to make an android road accident saver application, which notify selected contacts about road accident.

Tags: android, android-intent, accelerometer, android-sensors

I want to make an android road accident saver application, which notify selected contacts about road accident. I want to judge jerk by sensors and how we handle that?
is it possible by accelrometer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to judge jerk by differentiating the accelerometer data, but most smartphones' accelerometers don't have enough range to give you useful data at the kinds of accelerations involved in road accidents.

You'll need to do a lot of analysis and collect real data to be able to write an algorithm that distinguishes a road accident from, say, dropping the phone on the floor or tapping it hard on a desk.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever accident happens accelerometer will records the highest sensor value, but same values can even be recorded when your phone drops from your hand. I will suggest to use **mike, gyroscope**, etc sensors alongwith accelerometer so that you can correctly judge accidents and contacts are not notified mistakenly.